# Arena 1v1 On Trinitycore 3.3.5a Rated Arena Queue

Tags: trinitycore

i decided to open a question here because this is a super complexed issue for me which myself and 4 of my developers cannot fix or reproduce.

Emulator: Trinitycore 3.3.5a Version
Database, latest trinity 3.3.5a Database

I successfully applied a patch that simply changes arena 5v5 to 1v1 , the patch is very small and only changes amount of players required to join 5v5. The patch applies and compiles without warnings or errors. When testing on my local machine it works like a charm. It queues to 1v1 Rated and Unrated without any problems. When I run the script on my Dedicated server where my server is hosted, that patch will not queue to RATED arena 1v1, it will oonly allow UNRATED aka Skirmish Queue! However testing 2v2 and 3v3 you can queue just fine both rated and unrated.

We are stuck on the same place here, the 2v2 and 3v3 queue is working as intended. However 1v1 simply will not queue to Rated. We are using the same core, database on our dedicated server.

If anyone can give me some assistance with this or point me to the right direction it would greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you in this way. We need to take a look on that patc and also your modified files in core

Answer (score 0):

After looking for the patch for arena 1v1, there is one thing that caught my attention, it doesn't have a hook to check the worldconfig file for arena points distribution in case it is set to Instant vs Weekly, therefore if your worldconfig settings are set to distribute arena points your rated 1v1 will never queue! it always has to be set to true/1.

Thank you